# Problem with parallel iterative merge sort using OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp, mergesort

I need to parallelize iterative merge sort (not using recursion) using OpenMP.

The excellent code for it is here:

https://www.techiedelight.com/iterative-merge-sort-algorithm-bottom-up

But the resulting array is no longer sorted after using pragma parallel for.

```
// Iteratively sort array A[low..high] using temporary array
void mergesort(int A[], int temp[], int low, int high)
{
    int m, i;
    // divide the array into blocks of size m
    // m = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16...]
    for (m = 1; m <= high - low; m = 2*m)
    {
        // for m = 1, i = 0, 2, 4, 6, 8
        // for m = 2, i = 0, 4, 8
        // for m = 4, i = 0, 8
        // ...
        #pragma omp parallel for private (i)
        for (i = low; i < high; i += 2*m)
        {
            int from = i;
            int mid = i + m - 1;
            int to = min(i + 2*m - 1, high);

            merge(A, temp, from, mid, to);
        }
    }
}
```

I have written such a code to check if the array is sorted, but it has shown that the resulting array is not sorted.

```
void check(int A[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] > A[i + 1])
        {
            cout << "Array is not sorted" << endl;
            return;
        }
    }
    cout << "Array is sorted" << endl;
}
```

So, my code using pragma is wrong. Could you help me please to parallelize correctly iterative merge sort with OpenMP? I have to use pragma ("parallel", "for"). Is it possible?

Comment: Is the array correctly sorted without the `#pragma omp`? The loop variable definitions should be part of the for loop (`for (int i = low; `), then you won't need the `private(i)` on the OMP directive.  What is the implementation for `merge`? [Edit] the question to include these details.